# Check checkbox using core JavaScript and event handler

Tags: javascript

I am working on the below demo. How can I add an event listener and handler to a `#checker` button to check the checkbox with the value of `Benz` using core JavaScript?

```js
function checkBenz(){

}

var el = document.getElementById("checker");
el.addEventListener("click", checkBenz);
```

```html
<button id="checker">Check Benz</button> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Benz"> Benz <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="BMW"> BMW <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox has a `checked` property. Set it to true in order to check your checkbox with plain JavaScript.

```js
function checkBenz(){
  var benz = document.querySelector('input[value="Benz"]');
  benz.checked = !benz.checked;
  //or simply benz.checked = true,  if you don't want to toggle
}

var el = document.getElementById("checker");
el.addEventListener("click", checkBenz);
```

```html
<button id="checker">Check Benz</button> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Benz"> Benz <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="BMW"> BMW <br />
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz but I need to do this using checkbox vaues not ID

Comment: the querySelector assumes that there's only a single checkbox with the value 'Benz' - thus, querySelectorAll is recommended.

Comment: @kaizer1v yes. If OP needs more buttons like this one, I'd suggest wrapping inputs in a `<div id="cars"></div>` or similar, attach listener to it and use event delegation. I also suggested using id's instead of certain values

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly - it should help you.

```
<button id="checker">Check Benz</button> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Benz"> Benz <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="BMW"> BMW <br />
<script>
    function checkBenz(){
        document.querySelector("input[value=Benz]").setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }

    var el = document.getElementById("checker");
    el.addEventListener("click", checkBenz);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic way to handle your checking/un-checking of your checkboxes. Given a value for the checkbox you have, and the state you want to put it in - you can alter the checkboxes

```
function checkByName(value, check) {
    // given a checkbox value, check/un-check it
    var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[value='+value+']')

    cbs.forEach(function(elem, ind) {
      elem.checked = check
    })
  }
```

And now you can trigger this using the click event on the button like

```
var btn = document.getElementById('checker')
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkByName('Benz', true)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
function checkBenz(){
    document.querySelector(`input[value="Benz"]`).setAttribute("checked", "true");
}

var el = document.getElementById("checker");
el.addEventListener("click", checkBenz);
```

```html
<button id="checker">Check Benz</button> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="Benz"> Benz <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="BMW"> BMW <br />
```